Deploy angular image on heroku using
I have created an angular project and created a Dockerfile at root location:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:18.19.1-bullseye-slim as builder

RUN mkdir /project
WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@13

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . .
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

FROM builder as dev-envs

RUN <<EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git
EOF

RUN <<EOF
useradd -s /bin/bash -m vscode
groupadd docker
usermod -aG docker vscode
EOF
# install Docker tools (cli, buildx, compose)
COPY --from=gloursdocker/docker / /

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`

I am able to build an image and run the container locally, but once the image is deployed on heroku using the following commands:
heroku container:push web
heroku cintainer:release web

I get the following error:
2024-06-01T16:36:30.141302+00:00 app[web.1]: Application bundle generation complete. [13.067 seconds]
2024-06-01T16:36:30.141560+00:00 app[web.1]: Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
2024-06-01T16:36:30.353448+00:00 app[web.1]:   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
2024-06-01T16:36:30.353581+00:00 app[web.1]:   ➜  Network: http://172.18.247.62:4200/
2024-06-01T16:36:41.409685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=724M(141.5%)
2024-06-01T16:36:41.411326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2024-06-01T16:37:01.445703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=724M(141.5%)
2024-06-01T16:37:01.448544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2024-06-01T16:37:15.385895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2024-06-01T16:37:15.400323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2024-06-01T16:37:15.565276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2024-06-01T16:37:15.594316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed*

Did anybody ever encountered the same issue and knows how to set the $PORT variable in my angular project?
In the past I successfully deployed an (image)  express.js application on heroku where I could just use the $PORT variable in my code to get the (dynamic) value set by heroku - but in the case of an angular application I dont kknow how to move.

Please add proper formatting to error blocks and the docker script
